# Calculating ratio of diffrent category in one column in python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am new to Python. I have a data frame such as following, I want to calculate ratio of each category with respect to all category. I also want to calculate the ratio of Plus+ Premium with respect to the all category. can anyone help me?

```
product_tier    count
0   Basic   75421
1   Premium 2324
2   Plus    576
```

I wrote the code below, but I don't know how to make it work.

```
m=((ratio[ratio.product_tier =="Premium"].sum())+(ratio[ratio.product_tier =="Plus"].sum()))
m

n=(ratio[ratio.product_tier].sum())
r=m/n
```

The out put that I want is such a following table:

```
product_tier    count.  Ratio  ratio(Plus+ Premium)
0   Basic   75421.       x.       u

1   Premium 2324.        x.       u
2   Plus    576.         x.       u
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research:

df["Ratio"] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: x / x.sum())
df